# Shell script to recursively grep data from certain files in the directory and return values to file

Tags: shell, shell-script, scripting

I am making a simple shell script which will minimize the time I spend in searching all directories under a parent directory and grep some things inside some files. Here's my script.

```
#!/bin/sh
MainDir=/var/opt/database/1227-1239/

cd "$MainDir"

for dir in $(ls); do

grep -i "STAGE,te_start_seq Starting" "$dir"/his_file | tail -1 >> /home/xtee/sst-logs.out

if [ -f "$dir"/sysconfig.out];
then
    grep -A 1 "Drive Model" "$dir"/sysconfig.out | tail -1 >> /home/xtee/sst-logs.out
else
    grep -m 1 "Physical memory size" "$dir"/node0/setupsys.out | tail -1 >> /home/xtee/sst-logs.out
fi

done
```

The script is supposed to grep the string `STAGE,te_start_seq Starting` under the file `his_file` then dump it `sst-logs.out` which it does. My problem though is the part in the `if` statement. The script should check the current directory for `sysconfig.out`, grep `drive model` and dump it to `sst-logs.out` if it exists, otherwise, change directory to `node0` then grep `physical memory size` from `setupsys.out` and dump it to `sst-logs.out`. My problem is, it seems the `if then else` statement seems not to work as it doesn`t dump any data at all but if i execute grep manually, i do have data.

What is wrong with my shell script? Is there any more efficient way in doing this?

Comment: STOP CROSSPOSTING THIS QUESTION. WE ARE NOT AMUSED.

Comment: You need to be a little more specific

Comment: Please don't [cross-post all over the place](http://unix.stackexchange.com/faq#cross-posting). Closing here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if [ -r "$dir"/sysconfig.out ];
```

Notice the whitespace between `t` and `]`.